# MySql event which updates daily and alters some items in the database based on their contents

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

Basically, I am creating a simple auction website. I want the code to check every night at 9 PM for items which are set to expire today. If it finds any, it should insert the highest bidder into the database as the buyer. Here is what I have so far, which is not working:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    EVENT `sold` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-05-03 21:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN
        declare amt int;
        declare counter int;
        set counter=0;
        set amt = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ITEMS;
        declare test;
while (counter < amt)
begin
    set test = select Visibility FROM ITEMS where Keyy = counter;
    if (test == 1)
        set test = select sold from ITEMS where Keyy = counter;
        if (!test)
            set test = select Exp from ITEMS where Keyy = counter;
            if (test == CURDATE())
                UPDATE ITEMS SET `sold`= `bidder` WHERE Keyy =counter;
set counter = counter + 1;

end

    END */$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Do you have access cron jobs?

Comment: 'Today' being any time between 9 and midnight?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix It is on a windows server so I could use scheduled tasks potentially.

Comment: @Strawberry by Today I mean any post set to expire today. I did not have users input times, just dates

Comment: I see - so they're sealed bids?

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers for `DECLARE`d variables in MySQL do not begin with `@`; that is only for "session" variables (that are global to the connection to the database).

Also:

- "test" was not declared with a type
- `==` is not the equality operator in MySQL, just `=`
- `set variable = select ...` can have problems if the select cannot guarantee a single result; some of those may need `LIMIT 1` clauses.... though it looks like you're just checking for existence of data, so `EXISTS` queries might be more helpful for those.
- your count increment at the end is missing a SET
- `*/` does not belong there, it is to close block comments.

---

Also

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at its start, **before any other statements**.

from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html

This means you cannot interleave DECLAREs and SETs.

Comment: thank you! I have updated it, but it still does not run effectively.

Comment: see edit for list of stuff I noticed besides the variable names.

Comment: Thank you for all of this. It has been a great help. I am struggling with variable declarations. I feel like it is correct, but it keeps throwing errors. `DECLARE amt INT;
        SET amt = SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ITEMS;
        DECLARE test char(80) = "";
        DECLARE counter INT;
        SET counter = 0;`